# Primefaces call ConfirmDialog from Backing

Tags: java, primefaces

I would like to call `confirmDialog` via backing. This code works perfectly, but how can I set the message and set the actionlistener of the confirmDialog via backing? There is two condition, while:

- *The user check the option A on the checkbox (I omitted the code), then it should be directly print a text to console.* --> This one is done by the code below
- The user check the option B on the checkbox, then it should be show the confirmDialog and while the user press YES button, it should be call another function on the backing.

How to do that? Thanks.

```
<p:commandButton value="Execute" icon="ui-icon-circle-check"  update="frmContent" actionListener="#{backing.validate}" />

<p:confirmDialog id="cfmDlg" widgetVar="wvCfmDlg" global="true" >
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

In Backing:

```
public void validate() {
    if(mode.equals("1")) {
        System.out.println("OK");
    } else {
        //call confirmDialog and set message + action listener
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.execute("wvCfmDlg.show();");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "action listener of ConfirmDialog via backing bean????

Comment: @Makky: I mean, how can I set the `actionlistener` + `message` of confirmDialog via backing bean (in xhtml, you should do something like: `actionListener=""` and `message=""`) just like in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly.. I would do it in this way.

***xhtml***

```
<p:commandButton style="display: none" 
                 widgetVar="confirmButton"  
                 actionListener="#{backing.yesFunction}" >
   <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" /> 
</p:commandButton>

<p:commandButton value="Execute"
                 actionListener="#{backing.validate}" /> 

<p:confirmDialog id="cfmDlg" global="true" >
      <p:commandButton value="Yes" />
      <p:commandButton value="No" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

***bean***

```
public void validate() {
   if(mode.equals("1")) {
       System.out.println("OK");
   } else {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('confirmButton').jq.click();");
   }
}
```

Basically you add a hidden button (with p:confirm) in the usual way and you click it through jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @HatemAlimam little info for PrimeFaces version higher 5.0 you should use context.execute("PF('confirmButton').jq.click();");

Comment: @ÖmerFarukKurt you are right, since it's a bit old post I haven't updated it, now it's corrected :)